# How to make an error msg with invalid username/password appear under the username/password boxes

Tags: php

Here is the code of the username check I don't know how to make a code for the error message

```
    <?php
if ($_POST['username']) {
include_once "connect_to_mysql.php";
$username = stripslashes($_POST['username']);
$username = strip_tags($username);
$username = mysql_real_escape_string($username);
$password = ereg_replace("[^A-Za-z0-9]", "", $_POST['password']); 
$password = md5($password);
$sql = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM Users WHERE Us_Name='$username' AND Us_Password='$password'"); 
$login_check = mysql_num_rows($sql);
if($login_check > 0){ 
    while($row = mysql_fetch_array($sql)){ 
        $id = $row["Us_ID"];   
        $_SESSION['Us_ID'] = $id;
        $username = $row["Us_Name"];   
        $_SESSION['Us_Name'] = $username;
        header("location: Home2.php?id=$id"); 
    } 
} else {
  $msg = '<br /><br /><font color="#FF0000">Invalid User Or Pass </font><br />';
  exit();
}
}
?>
```

Add this is the code of the form.
I want the message to appear under the boxes of username and password

```
<form action="Home.php" method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data" name="loginform" id="loginform">
<input type="text" id="username" placeholder="Email or Username"/>
<input type="password" id="password" placeholder="Password"/>
<input type="submit" id="login_button" value="Login">
<p id="reset_password">Forget your password? Reset it <a href="reset_password.html">here</a>.</p>
</form>
```

I want the message to look like something like this

[errorMsg](https://i.stack.imgur.com/7fEJf.png)

Comment: What version of PHP are you using? You could make the form submit via ajax; on success redirect with JS; on failure display error below. As is your form isn't on the page when you output the invalid message. You shouldn't be modifying the user's passwords

Comment: It's almost 2016, it's time time to stop using md5 for password hashing. Also `mysql_*` functions are obsolete and removed in PHP 7.

Comment: http://jayblanchard.net/proper_password_hashing_with_PHP.html

Comment: I am using PHP 6.0.0-dev

Comment: There is no PHP 6 I'm familiar with. You should be using `preg_replace`, not `ereg_replace` though. Also use `mysqli` or `pdo`, not `mysql_`.

Comment: I just need to know how to make an error appear under the form if the username/password is wrong

Comment: something like this [link](http://i.stack.imgur.com/HUV8s.png)

Comment: you have many problems with your code. Another being no name attributes for your inputs. Error reporting would've helped you out here. Most or all of the functions you're using here, are either deprecated or deleted from your version of PHP.

Answer (score 0):

Instead of:

```
print '<br /><br /><font color="#FF0000">Invalid User Or Pass </font><br />';
```

Do:

```
$msg = '<br /><br /><font color="#FF0000">Invalid User Or Pass </font><br />';
```

And then in the HTML, do this:

```
<form action="Home.php" method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data" name="loginform" id="loginform">
<input type="text" id="username" placeholder="Email or Username"/>
<input type="password" id="password" placeholder="Password"/>

<?php echo $msg; ?> <!-- Here is where the message will appear -->

<input type="submit" id="login_button" value="Login">
<p id="reset_password">Forget your password? Reset it <a href="reset_password.html">here</a>.</p>
</form>
```

**EDIT:** Also, no need to `exit();`. Simply create the variable so you can `echo` it wherever you want it in your HTML by embedding your PHP in it.

Only printing will put it at the very top of the page, even before the `<!DOCTYPE html>`.